# MySQL Stored Procedure not functioning properly Nested cursors

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Please note the first cursor fetches 3 results and when I insert it inserts only 1. Earlier when I did not have open curs2, it was functioning fine, but now it doesn't. I might have missed some with done and done2 variables as I am writing a stored procedure after a long time. Please see if you may find anything wrong. 
Thanks

```
BLOCK1: begin

    declare done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    declare gid BIGINT;
    declare activity_name VARCHAR(255) ;
    declare type_1 VARCHAR(255) ;
    declare shop_activity_id BIGINT;
    declare curs CURSOR for select id, activityName, `Type`, shopActivityId from gantttask where `Type` = 'Project';

    open curs;
        LOOP1: loop
        fetch curs into gid, activity_name, type_1, shop_activity_id;
        if done then
            leave LOOP1;
        end if;
        insert into gantttask_result VALUES (gid, activity_name, type_1, shop_activity_id);

        BLOCK2: begin
            declare done2 INT DEFAULT FALSE;
            declare gid2 BIGINT;
            declare activity_name2 VARCHAR(255) ;
            declare type_2 VARCHAR(255) ;
            declare shop_activity_id2 BIGINT;
            declare curs2 CURSOR for select id, activityName, `Type`, shopActivityId from gantttask where `Type` != 'Project' and shopActivityId = shop_activity_id order by id;

            open curs2;
                LOOP2: loop
                fetch curs2 into gid2, activity_name2, type_2, shop_activity_id2;
                if done2 then
                    leave LOOP2;
                end if;

                end loop LOOP2;
            close curs2;
        end BLOCK2;

        end loop LOOP1;
    close curs;
end BLOCK1
```

Comment: Where are the handlers declared?

Comment: I havent declared the handlers, as I said I am new to writing sprocs. I added one handler and the loop is going infinite loop.

Comment: I suggest you review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html with particular reference to the role of handlers,

Comment: I added the handlers and it works now. thanks!